# Are we supposed to use properties or private fields in Blazor code behind classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor, certain things like injected objects and parameters must use properties, that part is clear.

But what about those page-specific variables, such as data/DTOs and misc strings/booleans etc used to control the page content and flow?

Is it better to use automatic properties with these all the way (public or private?) or private fields?

I'm asking this because in the various examples, tutorials and documentations related Blazor, use of both properties and fields are all over the place. I cannot seem to find any official best-practice guides on this.

Comment: I use fields for anything that doesn't require a property

Comment: Reasonable question.  Developers choice.  Personally I keep everything private except: properties used in inheritance which are protected, parameters or properties that need to be set externally which are public.   Property vs Field ?